# How to always show "Library" in the Finder its "Go"-Menu without holding a modifier key?

Tags: macos, finder, menu-bar, library

I often use the "Library" folder in my home folder `~/`.
The Library folder there (`~/Library/`) is shown (unhidden), and that is not the question.

I would like to also always show the menu point "Library" in the Finder menu under the word "Go".
Normally it only shows when I hold the <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> key the menu is open.
I tried to assign "Library" to the shortcut for "Downloads" and gave Downloads another shortcut, like it worked for "Save As…". But it only shows up then holding down the <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> key.

How to always show the "Library" menu point under the Finder "Go" menu, **without** holding down a key?

*In the screenshot I am **holding down the <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> key**:*

[image: the menu while holding the option key down]

Comment: Usually assigning a custom shortcut to a secondary menu item would do that, but it doesn't seem to work in this case.

Comment: I don't have access to OSX to test, does it work if you make the folder unhidden using `chflags nohidden ~/Library`?

Comment: Like I said in the question, the folder ~/Library/ is unhidden. I can see the folder in Finder with no problem, therefore I also wanted the menu point to be always shown.

Comment: My workflow involves using Alfred (or quicksilver), it's like spotlight. I just press `CTRL` + `Space`, and typing Library and hitting enter.

Comment: Not exactly what you want but it might be helpful: hold the option key and get your Library folder open. Drag the proxy (in the Library window's titlebar) to a Finder window's sidebar. That will give you quick access down the road. Handy when you're in an Open or Save dialog box and need to get to your Library folder.

Comment: This is a nice easy workaround! Open the library in a new finder window (go + alt + click library). The new finder window has a blue library icon in the top center of the toolbar. Drag and drop this onto the sidebar and it's available every time you open a finder window.

Answer (score 10):

There is no system-tweak-able setting (for now) that will change the "Go" menu behaviour.

Basically, whether you have a shortcut defined to open Library or not, you'll have to hold "Option" to make Library visible in the menu.

Alternatives from the comments for quick access to Library (as a workaround to it appearing) are to

- add ~/Library to your Finder toolbar
- add ~/Library to your Finder sidebar
- define a Finder keyboard shortcut
- unhide the folder with `chflags nohidden ~/Library`
- [automate typing](http://smilesoftware.com/TextExpander/index.html) ~/Library and use Go To… Command-Shift-G
- place the folder in the Dock or an alias to it on the Desktop (or elsewhere)

Comment: Quick Acces isn't the problem, as you can see in the screenshot I have assigned a shortcut. I want that the library option in the menu shows up.

Answer (score 7):

This isn't exactly what you've asked for, but it's as close as you can get for now. Open Terminal (in the Utilities folder) and type this command, and the Library folder will be visible in your home folder as it always was before Lion. The setting should stick until the next time you install an OS update, at which point Apple will "fix" the invisibility flag for you. Just do this again at that point, and all will be well.

```
chflags nohidden ~/Library
```

Answer (score 3):

The method for doing this has changed beginning with macOS Sierra (10.12). `chflags nohidden ~/Library` no longer works.

Instead, in Finder open up your home folder (`Macintosh HD/Users/username`), and *once inside* your home folder, press <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to see the View Options for that folder.

At the bottom of that window, tick the option to **Show Library Folder**.

[image]

See [this article](https://osxdaily.com/2016/12/12/show-user-library-folder-macos-sierra/) if you want a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This can only be fixed on Lion, not Mountain Lion:

Open System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts

In application shortcuts on the left, add an entry for Finder.app named Library (I used <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) and you should see it in Library - again only for 10.7 Mac OS X Lion.

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot, I used the same shortcut months ago. Seems like the problem only occurs on mountain lion.

Comment: I can confirm that on Mountain Lion - adding a shortcut does not make Library show in the menu (however the shortcut works as expected even though you don't see Library or the shortcut in the menu).